# How can I be sure that my keyboard is doing only what it supposed to do?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-events, malware, keylogger, malware-detection

I ordered a new keyboard and I want to be sure that it is safe to use (I saw the recommendations about it and it seems legit but still wanna be sure).
The problem is that I have another software on my computer that has sensitive information and It's a familiar software, how can I be sure that the keyboard doesn't have any undercover software which looking for that software and trying to steal the info or change it? Thanks.

I connected the keyboard to another computer but didnt knew how to check the keyboard.